# Camunda: How to restart process without instruction

Tags: business-process-management, camunda

I want to make a function to restart any process without reference to Process Key from the **start event**. The Code is following:

```
engine.runtimeService.restartProcessInstances(processDefinitionId)
    .processInstanceIds("processInstanceId")
    .execute()
```

While running this code I get an error: **Restart instructions cannot be empty**. So I add called method *startAfterActivity*

```
engine.runtimeService.restartProcessInstances(processDefinitionId)
    .processInstanceIds("processInstanceId")
    .startAfterActivity("StartEvent_Foo")
    .execute()
```

But now I'm supposed to guarantee that **start event** of every process is called "StartEvent_Foo".

Is it possible to restart a process instance without setting instruction?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<HistoricActivityInstance> activities = historyService.createHistoricActivityInstanceQuery()
        .processInstanceId("processInstanceId")
        .orderByHistoricActivityInstanceEndTime()
        .desc()
        .list();
```

If the process is already completed/canceled. You can get the latest activity of the process instance and use it later to get the id of that activity.

```
runtimeService.restartProcessInstances(historicProcessInstance.getProcessDefinitionId())
                .startAfterActivity(activities.get(0).getActivityId())
                .processInstanceIds(processInstanceId)
                .execute();
```